# Getting dynamic shape of tensors

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to create a custom metric in **Keras** with **tensorflow** backend.
Say, we have a minimalized metric, where we want to get the shape of a dynamic shaped tensor. I'm trying to do this as below:

```
def metric(y_true, y_pred):

    y_num = (tf.shape(y_true))[0]
    K.get_session().run(y_num)

    return anything
```

But I always get the error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_47_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?,?,?]
     [[Node: conv2d_47_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?,?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: metrics/metric/strided_slice/_1079 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_11_metrics/metric/strided_slice", tensor_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

I can't figure out, where could be the problem.
And if there is some problem in my code, how can I still get the shape some other way?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Model code:

```
ACTIVATION = "relu"

def convolution_block(x, filters, size, strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation=True):
    x = Conv2D(filters, size, strides=strides, padding=padding)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    if activation == True:
        x = Activation(ACTIVATION)(x)
    return x

def residual_block(blockInput, num_filters=16):
    x = Activation(ACTIVATION)(blockInput)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = convolution_block(x, num_filters, (3,3) )
    x = convolution_block(x, num_filters, (3,3), activation=False)
    x = Add()([x, blockInput])
    return x

# Build model
def build_model(input_layer, start_neurons, DropoutRatio = 0.5):
    # 101 -> 50
    conv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(input_layer)
    conv1 = residual_block(conv1,start_neurons * 1)
    conv1 = residual_block(conv1,start_neurons * 1)
    conv1 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1)
    pool1 = Dropout(DropoutRatio/2)(pool1)

    # 50 -> 25
    conv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(pool1)
    conv2 = residual_block(conv2,start_neurons * 2)
    conv2 = residual_block(conv2,start_neurons * 2)
    conv2 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2)
    pool2 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(pool2)

    # 25 -> 12
    conv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(pool2)
    conv3 = residual_block(conv3,start_neurons * 4)
    conv3 = residual_block(conv3,start_neurons * 4)
    conv3 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv3)
    pool3 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(pool3)

    # 12 -> 6
    conv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(pool3)
    conv4 = residual_block(conv4,start_neurons * 8)
    conv4 = residual_block(conv4,start_neurons * 8)
    conv4 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv4)
    pool4 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(pool4)

    # Middle
    convm = Conv2D(start_neurons * 16, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(pool4)
    convm = residual_block(convm,start_neurons * 16)
    convm = residual_block(convm,start_neurons * 16)
    convm = Activation(ACTIVATION)(convm)

    # 6 -> 12
    deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(convm)
    uconv4 = concatenate([deconv4, conv4])
    uconv4 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(uconv4)

    uconv4 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 8, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(uconv4)
    uconv4 = residual_block(uconv4,start_neurons * 8)
    uconv4 = residual_block(uconv4,start_neurons * 8)
    uconv4 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(uconv4)

    # 12 -> 25
    #deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv4)
    deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid")(uconv4)
    uconv3 = concatenate([deconv3, conv3])    
    uconv3 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(uconv3)

    uconv3 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 4, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(uconv3)
    uconv3 = residual_block(uconv3,start_neurons * 4)
    uconv3 = residual_block(uconv3,start_neurons * 4)
    uconv3 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(uconv3)

    # 25 -> 50
    deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv3)
    uconv2 = concatenate([deconv2, conv2])

    uconv2 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(uconv2)
    uconv2 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 2, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(uconv2)
    uconv2 = residual_block(uconv2,start_neurons * 2)
    uconv2 = residual_block(uconv2,start_neurons * 2)
    uconv2 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(uconv2)

    # 50 -> 101
    #deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(uconv2)
    deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="valid")(uconv2)
    uconv1 = concatenate([deconv1, conv1])

    uconv1 = Dropout(DropoutRatio)(uconv1)
    uconv1 = Conv2D(start_neurons * 1, (3, 3), activation=None, padding="same")(uconv1)
    uconv1 = residual_block(uconv1,start_neurons * 1)
    uconv1 = residual_block(uconv1,start_neurons * 1)
    uconv1 = Activation(ACTIVATION)(uconv1)

    uconv1 = Dropout(DropoutRatio/2)(uconv1)
    output_layer = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(uconv1)
    #output_layer = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(uconv1)

    return output_layer
```

Comment: The error does not seem to be relevant to the metric you defined; rather, it seems to be a problem somewhere else in your model code. Don't you get this error if you use a built-in metric instead?

Comment: @today I've got no errors using built-in metrics or other custom metrics, which don't want to get (evaluate) the shape of the input tensor.

Comment: @today Yes, Node: conv2d_47_target Placeholder feed error doesn't seem to be relevant to the metric, I just want to roll back the source of error and that was the point, where I'm out of ideas -so far-, because the model works fine anyway with any other metric.

Comment: @today Thank you for your efforts to force me to recheck, it was a duplicated row in the model, which didn't cause errors any other way. :)

Comment: @today But the issue remained still with conv2d_46_target...

Comment: Please include your model code in the question as well.

Comment: @today Sure, see update